# Find and select multiple cells within a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, select, replace, subscript

I am new to writing macros and have search everywhere for a solution to my problem with no luck, so I'm hoping for some help here.

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing multiple calculation which are automated. This means a big part of the spreadsheet is locked for other users who only need to do the calculations. Basically what I want is to have this spreadsheet in two different languages. So using a macro I want to change all the text content in my spreadsheet from one language to another. Since i only want one spreadsheet (because I keep updating it and adding new calculations to it) I thought a macro with a button to switch between the 2 language was the best solution.

Here is my problem. I used find and replace to replace each word which is working fine.

```
Sub Rename_EN()
'
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="rød", Replacement:="red", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="grøn", Replacement:="green", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="blå", Replacement:="blue", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="Flt-tag", Replacement:="FLT-roof", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

 ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

But the text also have technical terms, fx. I want F_(LT-tag) to be replaced with F_(LT-roof), but with (LT-roof) as a sub-scripted text.

I searched for a long time and came to the conclusion that it is not possible to simple subscript the text in a code. (if it is, then please feel free to tell me how :)) I then found this code that can change specific characters to subscript and superscript:

```
Sub Super_Sub()
Dim NumSub
Dim NumSuper
Dim SubL
Dim SubR
Dim SuperL
Dim SuperR
Dim CheckSub
Dim CounterSub
Dim CheckSuper
Dim CounterSuper
Dim Cell
'
CheckSub = True
CounterSub = 0
CheckSuper = True
CounterSuper = 0
Cell = ActiveCell
'
NumSub = Len(Cell) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cell, "[", ""))
NumSuper = Len(Cell) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cell, "{", ""))
'
If Len(Cell) = 0 Then Exit Sub
If IsError(Application.Find("[", ActiveCell, 1)) = False Then
Do
    Do While CounterSub <= 1000
        SubL = Application.Find("[", ActiveCell, 1)
        SubR = Application.Find("]", ActiveCell, 1)
        ActiveCell.Characters(SubL, 1).Delete
        ActiveCell.Characters(SubR - 1, 1).Delete
        ActiveCell.Characters(SubL, SubR - SubL - 1).Font.Subscript = True
        CounterSub = CounterSub + 1
        If CounterSub = NumSub Then
            CheckSub = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Loop Until CheckSub = False
End If
'
'
If IsError(Application.Find("{", ActiveCell, 1)) = False Then
Do
    Do While CounterSuper <= 1000
        SuperL = Application.Find("{", ActiveCell, 1)
        SuperR = Application.Find("}", ActiveCell, 1)
        ActiveCell.Characters(SuperL, 1).Delete
        ActiveCell.Characters(SuperR - 1, 1).Delete
        ActiveCell.Characters(SuperL, SuperR - SuperL - 1).Font.Superscript = True
        CounterSuper = CounterSuper + 1
        If CounterSuper = NumSuper Then
            CheckSuper = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Loop Until CheckSuper = False
End If
'
End Sub
```

So I wanted to make a button that would run the macros in a specific order. The problem here is, that I need to select the cells with { and [ to run the code.

Can I rewrite this code to be used for a whole spreadsheet? I again searched for a solution and couldn't find one, so I tried to make yet another macro to run before this, that finds and selects all cells in a sheets containing { and [. Again I hit a wall since I can't get the it to select multiple cells in a whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing it is to have a second hidden sheet containing the replacement text in the relevant cells. You can then use `FIND` to find all cells containing a value, check it doesn't hold a formula and swap the value with that held in the second sheet.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sValue As String

    Dim MainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet

    'MainSheet contains your formula & text.
    'SecondSheet only contains values in the text cells.
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set MainSheet = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set SecondSheet = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    Set rCell = MainSheet.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext, True)
    If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = rCell.Address
        Do
            'If the cell doesn't contain a formula swap its value with
            'the value held in the second sheet.
            If Not rCell.HasFormula Then
                sValue = rCell.Value
                rCell.Value = SecondSheet.Range(rCell.Address).Value
                SecondSheet.Range(rCell.Address).Value = sValue
            End If
            Set rCell = MainSheet.Cells.FindNext(rCell)
        Loop While rCell.Address <> firstAddress
    End If

End Sub
```